# CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url

Tags: python, anaconda, spacy

I am trying to install spacy on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise with Anaconda3 + python 3.6 x64.

To do so I executed:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install spacy
```

This gives the error message `CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url`. What could the issue be?

The entire error message is as follows:

```
C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts>conda install spacy
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    cymem:      1.31.2-py36_vc14_0     conda-forge [vc14]
    dill:       0.2.6-py36_0           conda-forge
    ftfy:       4.4.2-py36_0           conda-forge
    murmurhash: 0.26.4-py36_vc14_0     conda-forge [vc14]
    plac:       0.9.6-py36_0
    preshed:    1.0.0-py36_vc14_0      conda-forge [vc14]
    pyreadline: 2.1-py36_0
    regex:      2017.04.05-py36_0      conda-forge
    spacy:      1.8.2-np112py36_vc14_0 conda-forge [vc14]
    termcolor:  1.1.0-py36_1           conda-forge
    thinc:      6.5.2-np112py36_vc14_0 conda-forge [vc14]
    tqdm:       4.14.0-py36_0          conda-forge
    ujson:      1.35-py36_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:      4.3.21-py36_0                      --> 4.3.22-py36_0 conda-forge

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

    conda-env:  2.6.0-0                            --> 2.6.0-0       conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)?


CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/conda-env-2.6.0-0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/conda-env-2.6.0-0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/conda-env-2.6.0-0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

I tried several times over the last few days with the same issue.

---

I tried `conda install spacy --no-deps`:

```
C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts>conda install spacy --no-deps
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    spacy: 1.8.2-np112py36_vc14_0 conda-forge [vc14]

Proceed ([y]/n)? y


CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/spacy-1.8.2-np112py36_vc14_0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/spacy-1.8.2-np112py36_vc14_0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/spacy-1.8.2-np112py36_vc14_0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

Even though I can access https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/spacy-1.8.2-np112py36_vc14_0.tar.bz2 with my web browser.

Comment: What happens if you do `conda install -c conda-forge conda-env`? What happens if you paste the URL into your browser (`https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/conda-env-2.6.0-0.tar.bz2`)? Does it ask to download the archive? What happens if you do `conda remove conda-env` and then install either `spacy` or `conda-env` itself if it failed before.

Comment: @a_guest Thanks. Interestingly today conda-env doesn't work today. It was working yesterday (I was doing the same test, and I see `conda-env-2.6.0-0.tar.bz2` in my download folder). Does that mean I should just wait or is there something I can fix?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify whether this is a network problem for example. So when you manage to download the file via your browser does the same error happen during `conda install`? Also I was curious to see whether the error happens in an isolated install attempt of `conda-env`: `conda install -c conda-forge conda-env`. Finally it would be good to see whether the problem can be resolved by removing `conda-env` and then reinstalling it from the `conda-forge` channel.

Comment: @a_guest `conda remove conda-env` gives the error message `RemoveError: Error: this 'remove' command cannot be executed because it
would require removing 'conda' dependencies
`

Comment: @a_guest  `conda install -c conda-forge conda-env` gives the error message `CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/conda-env-2.6.0-0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: None`

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt `conda install conda-env-2.6.0-0.tar.bz2` works. However,  when I do `conda install spacy` I still have the error message `CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/conda-env-2.6.0-0.tar.bz2>`

Comment: According to the documentation of [`conda install`](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-install.html) you may ignore dependencies during installation (`--no-deps`) and you can install the required ones manually later on (leaving out `conda-env`). Or even better seems to be the switch `--no-update-dependencies` which leaves all your dependencies in place during the installation (including `conda-env`). So I suggest trying `conda install --no-update-dependencies spacy`. If that doesn't work then `conda install --no-deps spacy` and installing the required dependencies manually.

Comment: @a_guest I tried `conda install spacy --no-update-dependencies`: 
[Why What does adding `--no-update-dependencies` add more updates with conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44833270/395857)

Comment: @a_guest I tried `conda install spacy --no-deps`: I have updated the question with the information.